# Not able to install redlibssh2 python library

Tags: python, cmake, pip, libssh2

Try to install using `pip install redlibssh2`.

But getting following exception where it mentions missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR:

```
   CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
      Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

After setting `ZLIB_ROOT`, `ZLIB_LIBRARY`, `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR`, not able to solve the issue.

Comment: So, where exactly have you zlib library installed and how exactly have you tried to set `ZLIB_ROOT` variable?

Comment: First I tried setting using this 
`ZLIB_ROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`

Also tried setting this path also . 
C:\src\win32\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows

which contain 
C:\src\win32\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\lib\zlib.lib
C:\src\win32\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\zlib.h
C:\src\win32\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\zconf.h